# LibGDX problems rotating sprite

Tags: java, android, rotation, libgdx, sprite

OK so I'm really confused I've rotated sprites before and had no problem such as rotating a boat as it moves through an ocean, but for some reason I'm having a really big problem this time. So I create a texture in an assets file, but not static textures. I load the texture using the following:

```
class Assets{
    Texture img;
    public Assets(){
        img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/PNG.png")
```

And then I call the assets in the main class by calling:

```
Assets assets = new Assets()
```

And then I have a class that is an animator just for this main character because his animation is so different and varied from other characters.

```
class Animations{
    Guy MYGUY;
    Texture firstTexture;
    ArrayList<Texture> running;
    Sprite CurrentSprite;
    public Animations(Texture standingStill, Guy myGuy){
        MYGUY = myGuy;
        firstTexture = standingStill;
        running = new ArrayList<Texture>();
        running.add(firstTexture);
        CurrentSprite = new Sprite(firstTexture);

    public void update (int direction, int state){
         CurrentSprite.setPosition(MYGUY.X, MYGUY.Y)
        // I have a switch here, but it does nothing yet because I haven't added in different actions for the character.
        //However I do have a switch for direction, because that is important right now
        switch(state){
        case Guy.LEFT:
            CurrentSprite.set rotation(180);
        //yes there are more, but even rotating 180 won't work correctly
        }
```

Then I have a renderer class to draw everything, i have the object `MyGuy` in an object for the world called `myLand` and I draw it with:

```
myLand.GUY.animation.CurrentSprite(batch);
```

So my problem arises on the rotation, whenever it rotates 180 degrees it seems to always rotate around the coordinates (0, 0) instead of the center of the sprite. So it usually ends up where I move like five to the right, but then if I try to go left it does double the distance backwards, but the camera position stays the same, and the guy usually disappears off the left or right side of the screen.

Comment: Try use `rotate(...)` method instead of `setRotation(...)`. With `setOrigin(widthSprite\2, heightSprite\2)`.

Comment: I'll try that when i get back to my computer in a couple of hours, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Just for curiosity: For the animations are you using libgdx animation? If not i would suggest to do that.

Comment: No I'm not, just because of the complexity of the main characters animation, however for the rest of the characters I am, but yes thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use `rotate(...)`method instead of `setRotation(...).`

With `setOrigin(widthSprite\2, heightSprite\2)` 

That action rotate sprite itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sprite.setOriginCenter();
```

This should help

Answer (score -1):

Instead of rotating the sprite, just flip it with this single line:

```
CurrentSprite.flip(true, false);
```

the first boolean is X flip (that's what you want to set as true when going left) and the second is the Y flip.

Comment: I would like to do that, but that doesn't work when i want to go up, this isn't a platform game... This is more of a 2d world, kind of like old gameboy style game where you control a main character from above. Like an eagle eye view, maybe somewhat like an old Pokemon look. So i need to be able to have the character face upward along with 45° angle and such

Comment: I'm actually doing a game with the same view type as you and it works fine! Do you want to illustrate your problem with pictures?

Comment: yes i would love to, but i don't know how because I only have my phone on me right now, and i don't know how, or if it's possible to add pictures on the mobile app