# cannot rotate my sprite in libgdx

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

so I've been looking at other people's questions and I've tried to apply the answers to my code but I do not seem to find how to do so. All I am trying to do is that when the Sprite moves is going to rotate at the same time. This is where I am calling the rotate function inside my Player class (which extends Sprite):

```
public void playerMovement(float dt){
    if(Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer)) {
        float roll = Gdx.input.getRoll();
        float pitch = Gdx.input.getPitch();



        final float MAX_SPEED = 0.4f;

        velocity.x = roll;
        velocity.y = pitch;
        x = position.x;
        y = position.y;

        if (Math.abs(velocity.x) > 1) {
            x = Math.max(0, Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), x + velocity.x * MAX_SPEED));
            position.x = x;
            position.y = y;
            rotate(90 * dt); //NOT WORKING
        }

        if (Math.abs(velocity.y) > 1) {
            y = Math.max(0, Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), y + velocity.y * MAX_SPEED));
            position.x = x;
            position.y = y;
            rotate(90* dt); //NOT WORKING
        }
    }
}
```

before it used to extend Actor and use setRotate(90 * dt) and it was working fine. I decided to change to Sprite because I did not want to depend on the stage.

here's how I am rendering the player inside my GameScreen:

```
game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(atlas2.findRegion("player"), player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, player.PLAYER_DIMENSION , player.PLAYER_DIMENSION);
game.batch.end();
```

I tried to use the player.draw(game.batch) function from the Sprite class, yet I did not work because I needed a Texture and the texture I am using is just an AtlasRegion and it did not let my type casted to a Texture

so if there are any suggestions on how to make my Sprite rotate I will appreciate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGDX problems rotating sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151098/libgdx-problems-rotating-sprite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sprite` holds the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing 2D sprite. In geometry, it carry sprite position, size, rotation and scale.

By using below method you're only passing position and size of player `Sprite`.

```
game.batch.draw(atlas2.findRegion("player"), player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, player.PLAYER_DIMENSION , player.PLAYER_DIMENSION);
```

Use in this way :

```
TextureAtlas atlas2=....;
Sprite player=new Sprite(atlas2.findRegion("player"));
```

and draw by using `draw` method of `Sprite`

`player.draw(game.batch);`

**EDIT**

```
public class Player extends Sprite {

   public Player(TextureRegion region){    // <- Add this constructor 
       super(region);
       ...
   }
}
```

And create object of `Player`

```
Player player=new Player(atlas2.findRegion("player");
```

Comment: ok but in this case, I'll not be making a Player class? because you are making a Sprite Object instead of a Player Object. I am not sure if I could just pass the Texture as a parameter to my Player class

Comment: According to your post `my Player class (which extends Sprite):` so I think you've constructor that accept textureRegion, Add If you don't have. I've edited my answer.

Comment: ok did it that way and it is rotating cool...but it rotates constantly no matter the if statements and also it won't change position!

Comment: You're updating `position` vector that is your player property, `Sprite` not using that property for drawing, so update x and y of Sprite by `setPosition(x,y);` otherwise override `draw(batch)` method of Sprite and draw by yourself

Comment: ok so decided to just setPosition(x, y) and it works perfect thank you very much for this. Just to know, if I decided to draw myself, what would I be adding to the draw method?

Comment: you need to calculate vertices of your sprite using your `position` co-ordinate and use batch method  `draw (Texture texture, float[] spriteVertices, int offset, int count);`